# Android: Tablayout comes up when keyboard open

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-tablayout, window-soft-input-mode

I am using TabLayout, which position in the bottom of the screen. The problem is 
when the keyboard open the TabLayout also comes above of the keyboard.

I want to hide behind the keyboard

In Manifest I set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`, if  I change to adjustSpan, even the tile bar goes up when keyboard open.

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tb_toolbar_main_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tb_heading"
                fontPath="@string/font_bebas_neue_bold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:text="@string/app_name_caps"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/heading_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/toolbar_title_text" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vp_activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="@color/white"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_back_selected"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabLayoutTextAppearance"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/home_sub_text"
    />
```

Comment: Instead take a relative layout as parent , then give your tablayout attribute alignparentbottom = true . Put the other layout above it . Hope this will help .

Answer (score 2):

I also face same issue and i fixed it by adding below code. Please try this

In build.gradle file

```
implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.2.1'
```

In Manifest.xml

```
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

In Activity class

```
TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);

KeyboardVisibilityEvent.setEventListener(
                MainActivity.this,
                new KeyboardVisibilityEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean isOpen) {
                        if(isOpen){
                            tabs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else {
                            tabs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: this solution is working, but this is kind of patching, do we know what is cause. I am confused will this solution cause any other issue

Comment: No, This solution will not cause any other issue in your screen layout or code. It will work fine in all case. I am using the same solution in my some projects.

Comment: @BinilSurendran, If this answer is helpful for you then can you please help me to get privilege into this community. Thanks in Advanced

Answer (score 0):

In you manifest add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustNothing"

Try to take the relative layout as parent layout and give your tablyout attribute as alignparentbottom= true.

Put the other layout above this tablayout.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I cant change it to relative layout, because a flickering issue will comes

Comment: Have you tried adjustNothing tag for windowsoftinoutmode

Comment: @MiniChip : Could u pls share some example. This is some how not working. The tabs continue to move up with keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: it will cause the tile bar also goes up, when keyboard open